# How can I select multi-column from table where date is last day?

Tags: c#, xcode, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm trying to select a field from my table where date is less than today.

```
connect.Open();
command.Connection = connect;
today = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
string query = "select attendance as [Attend], Emp_UserId as ID, 'Date_ofday' as [Today Date] , Emp_UserName as Name ,Delay_Hours as [Delay Hours] from Attendance where Date_ofday > '"+ DateTime.Parse(today) + "'  ";
command.CommandText = query;
OleDbDataAdapter da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt1 = new System.Data.DataTable();
da1.Fill(dt1);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
```

This gives a `data type miss` or `missing operator` error, using an Access DB.

Comment: I placed an answer but I didn't understand what db you are using. Is it MySql (tag) or MS Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting a DateTime to string and then parse it back to  DateTime in the next line, this doesn't make sense. I think you should use parameters, see if this works, I don't use MySql:

```
connect.Open();
command.Connection = connect;
todday = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
string query = "select attendance as [Attend], Emp_UserId as ID, 'Date_ofday' as [Today Date] , Emp_UserName as Name ,Delay_Hours as [Delay Hours] from Attendance where Date_ofday > @Today";
command.CommandText = query;
OleDbDataAdapter da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt1 = new System.Data.DataTable();
da1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Today", DateTime.Today);
da1.Fill(dt1);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
```

In the case you are using MS Access the query becomes:

```
string query = "select attendance as [Attend], Emp_UserId as ID, 'Date_ofday' as [Today Date] , Emp_UserName as Name ,Delay_Hours as [Delay Hours] from Attendance where Date_ofday > ?";
```

Comment: I using Access Data base , thank you so much it's work very well